# Multi Threading with Singletons

Tags: c#, multithreading, singleton

I'm developing a Print Queue for a centralized server which is in charge of directing print jobs to different servers depending on requirements.

I'm doing this as a WCF service which has a "Print" endpoint. This is all fine, I have got this set up, however I'm trying to develop a thread safe end point which can also return a count of the number of queued threads.

Below is an example class which fires up multiple threads and sends them to the "Print" method (which is emulating the behavior of multiple people hitting the end point at the same time)

```
public class ThreadStuff
{
    #region [Singleton Logic]

    private static ThreadStuff _instance;

    private ThreadStuff() { }

    private static ThreadStuff Instance
    {
        get { return _instance ?? (_instance = new ThreadStuff()); }
    }

    #endregion

    private static readonly object LockObject = new object();
    private int _queuedThreads;

    public static int QueuedThreads
    {
        get { return Instance._queuedThreads; }
    }

    public static void Start()
    {
        var threads = new Thread[10];
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var threadNumber = i;
            var t = new Thread(() => Instance.MyMethod(threadNumber));
            threads[i] = t;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var threadNumber = i;
            Thread.Sleep(50);
            threads[i].Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} started", threadNumber);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private void MyMethod(int threadNumber)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} entered MyMethod", threadNumber);
        Instance._queuedThreads++;

        lock (LockObject)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} entered MyMethod's Lock", threadNumber);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} finished Thread.Sleep", threadNumber);
        }

        Instance._queuedThreads--;
        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} exited MyMethod", threadNumber);
    }
}
```

This works as expected and produced the following:

[image]

However, I then added another project to my solution which will access the "QueuedThreads" property of this singleton (emulating the behavior of a polling end point).

This project is a simple win forms app with the following code

```
textBox1.Text = ThreadStuff.QueuedThreads.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

However, this always returns 0, the winforms app cannot see the Singleton data for the "ThreadStuff" class, it creates a new ThreadStuff instance. I've pinged this round my office and nobody can see why this is happening, and after multiple google searches I decided to ask here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your `_queuedThreads` variable needs to be `static`, I think.

Comment: The ThreadStuff Singleton lives in the console app and not in the WinForm app? They don't share memory do they.

Comment: Having done a lot of investigation and playing around with the suggestions given, I have found a solution.

I stuck the Singleton in an IoC container and when resolved, it contained the queued threads.

Thank you all for your answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case is probably because it's 2 different processes, one console application and one WinForm application. As long as that is the case, you need some sort interprosess communication to enable the WinForm application to see the queued up requests. There are several ways to do it. A few possibilities

- store the value in a database and read it from there in the WinForm application
- use a message queue/bus and publish a message which the WinForm application listens for
- named pipes
- sockets
- etc etc

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern:

```
using System;

public sealed class Singleton
{
   private static volatile Singleton instance;
   private static object syncRoot = new Object();

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null) 
         {
            lock (syncRoot) 
            {
               if (instance == null) 
                  instance = new Singleton();
            }
         }

         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```